# Why does a contenteditable div not behave like an input element?

Tags: html, html5

The motivation for the [content editable](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/) div would be to allow user input inside a normal div element. Why does it then behave so differently to input element? Mainly I am referring to the addition of a `div` or a `br` on line break.

Additionally it does not have a placeholder item. So my question is what is the point of content-editable div? Why would I want to use it at all?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> what is the point of content-editable div?

The purpose of a `contenteditable` element is to provide WYSIWYG capabilities for editing the content and structure of elements within a Web page.

> Why does it then behave so differently to input element?

A `contenteditable` element still has to render like a normal DOM element. To address your particular concern about line breaks, there is no way to express rendered line breaks in HTML without using an element like `<br>` or `<div>` (since normal source-code HTML line breaks aren't rendered in the visual page).

You might ask, "*Why, then, did the WHATWG (or Microsoft) not simply make `contenteditable` elements play by different rules from 'normal' elements?*" The answer is that a `contenteditable` element might *stop* being `contenteditable` at any time -- the status is toggleable. There is no obvious sensible way to make an element render its internal DOM differently depending on whether it is currently `contenteditable` or not.

Suppose non-`<br>` visible line breaks were allowed when the element was in a `contenteditable` state. When the element switches out of `contenteditable` mode, should the non-`<br>` line breaks then vanish? You might conceivably say, "*Yes, that's fine!*" to such a suggestion, but that flies in the face of the purpose of `contenteditable` I stated in my first sentence. Having the element change appearance based on its `contenteditable` state would spoil its usefulness as a WYSIWYG.

Comment: Nice answer. Part of my frustration with `contentedibale` was that I am making a [markdown editor](http://brislink.github.io/Abstract/) and the `br` spoils it completely. At least I understand the rationale behind it now. Thanks :)